# Concatenate two or more columns with Yii-ESelect2 extension in dropdown

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, yii-extensions, yii

[Eselect2](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/) is the extension am using and `myADropDown()` fetches the data and displays. But i need to concatenate two or more columns in the dropdown.

Model1 View:

```
<?php   
    $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
        'name' => 'id',
        'model' => $model,
        'options'  => array(
            'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('id'),
        ),
        'data' => $model->myADropDown(),
    ));
?>
```

Model1:

```
  public function getConcatened()
  {
       return $this->name.' '.$this->locate.' '.$this->rating;
  }

  public function myADropDown()
  {
      $vid=Yii::app()->SESSION['vid'];

      $gid=Model2::model()->xyz($vid);

      $list=CHtml::listData($gid,'id','concatened');
      return $list;
  }
```

In the dropdownlist i need: **name, location, rating for each person** but i am unable to do so.

Please, let me know how do i achieve it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is ESelect2 problem.

Look back the error message. It look like is this line problem
"$gid=Model2::model()->xyz($vid);" and you SQL not set correct.

Comment: i dont think theres any problem with the sql because before using eselect2 , the normal dropdownlist of yii was inserting the record

Answer (score 0):

This wrks

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'options'  => array(
            'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('id'),
         ),
         'data' => $model->myADropDown(),
    ));
?>
```